Java 8 compare list of integer and list of Object
I have input of Ids
List<Integer> idList = List.of(100, 101, 102, 103, 104);

from DB i got list of Objects
@Getter
@Builder
public class CustomObject {
   private int id;
}

List<CustomObject> fromDB = List.of(
    CustomObject.builder().id(102).build(), 
    CustomObject.builder().id(104).build()
);

I want to see difference between input IDs with response from DB CustomObject list
If response from DB does not contains id from input i want to see this difference
List<Integer> listOfID = fromDB.stream().map(CustomObject::getId).toList();

String list = idList.stream()
                    .filter(element -> !listOfID.contains(element))
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println("RESULT: " + list);

RESULT: 100, 101, 103

I don't have a big experience on Stream API is it possible to simplify my implementation?

Collection::retainAll?

Yea ... you shouldn't use streams for this.  It is a set difference problem so try using Set operations.

Streams have a lot of overhead and sets
tend to be more efficient for this type of operation.
Just remove those from the db in the original set.
Set<Integer> idList = new HashSet<>(Set.of(100, 101, 102, 103, 104));
Set<Integer> fromDb = Set.of(102,104);
idList.removeAll(fromDb);
System.out.println(idList);

prints
[100, 101, 103]

Or just take your list and use a simple loop.
for (CustomerObject co : fromDb) {
    idList.remove(co.getId());
}


I'd convert the list fromDB to a set of IDs and then remove it from idList it to get the difference:
Set<Integer> fromDBIntegers = 
    fromDB.stream().map(CustomObject::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
String difference =
    idList.stream()
          .filter(id -> !fromDBIntegers.contains(id))
          .map(String::valueOf)
          .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

